# export two gridview in two different excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to export two gridview in two different excel,
but while exporting i getting exception on `Respose.end()` of first gridview `(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)`.

```
           {//export firstgrid 
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            DataTable dtGetReportBank = new DataTable();
            dtGetReportBank = objPO.GetReportBank(id);
            gridData1.DataSource = dtGetReportBank;
            gridData1.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "BankCMS" + ".xls"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw1 = new HtmlTextWriter(sw1);
            gridData1.AllowPaging = false;
            dvContent.RenderControl(htw1);
            Response.Write(sw1.ToString());
            Response.End();
            Btn.Visible = false;
            }
            //export second grid
            {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            DataTable dtGetReportBank = new DataTable();
            dtGetReportBank = objPO.GetReportBank(id);
            gridData.DataSource = dtGetReportBank;
            gridData.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "BankCMS" + ".xls"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw1 = new HtmlTextWriter(sw1);
            gridData.AllowPaging = false;
            dvContent.RenderControl(htw1);
            Response.Write(sw1.ToString());
            Response.End();
            Btn.Visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest to add those two excel files in a zip archive and only then put these in the request

Comment: Can u please tell how we can export it into zip

Comment: read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx